# replace list element with another and return the new list

Tags: scala

I am kind of stuck with this, and I know this is a bloody simple question :(

I have a case class such as:

```
case class Students(firstName: String, lastName: String, hobby: String)
```

I need to return a new list but change the value of `hobby` based on Student name. For example:

```
val classToday = List(Students("John","Smith","Nothing"))
```

Say if student name is `John` I want to change the hobby to `Soccer` so the resulting list should be:

```
List(Students("John","Smith","Soccer")
```

I think this can be done via map? I have tried:

```
classToday.map(x => if (x.firstName == "John") "Soccer" else x)
```

This will just replace `firstName` with `Soccer` which I do not want, I tried setting the "True" condition to `x.hobby == "Soccer"` but that does not work.

I think there is a simple solution to this :(

Comment: stye `Students` is immutable, so you have to create new `Students` instance to change hobby. `classToday.map(x => if (x.firstName == "John") x.copy(hoddy="Soccer") else x)`. Method `copy` clones instance `Students` with hobby filed changed.

Comment: Style note: If a single value of your case class only represents one student, it's best to name it `Student` and not `Students`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda function in `map` has to return a `Students` value again, not just `"Soccer"`. For example, if you had to replace *everyone*'s hobbies with `"Soccer"`, this is not right:

```
classToday.map(x => "Soccer")
```

What you want is [the `copy` function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html#copying):

```
classToday.map(x => x.copy(hobby = "Soccer"))
```

Or for the original task:

```
classToday.map(x => if (x.firstName == "John") x.copy(hobby = "Soccer") else x)
```

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for!  I tried a .replace but it didnt look like .replace was available for list

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern-matching syntax to pretty up this type of transition.

```
val newList = classToday.map{
                case s@Students("John",_,_) => s.copy(hobby = "Soccer")
                case s => s
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make it more generic, you can create a map of names to hobbies:

For example:

```
val firstNameToHobby = Map("John" -> "Soccer", "Brad" -> "Basketball")
```

And use it as follows:

```
case class Students(firstName: String, lastName: String, hobby: String)

val classToday = List(Students("John","Smith","Nothing"), Students("Brad","Smith","Nothing"))

val result = classToday.map(student => student.copy(hobby = firstNameToHobby.getOrElse(student.firstName, "Nothing"))) 

// result = List(Students(John,Smith,Soccer), Students(Brad,Smith,Basketball))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can create a mapping between the firstName of the student with Hobby, then you can use it like this:

```
scala> val hobbies = Map("John" -> "Soccer", "Messi" -> "Soccer", "Williams" -> "Cricket")
hobbies: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(John -> Soccer, Messi -> Soccer, Williams -> Cricket)

scala> case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: String, hobby: String)
defined class Student

scala> val students = List(Student("John", "Smith", "Nothing"), Student("Williams", "Lopez", "Nothing"), Student("Thomas", "Anderson", "Nothing"))
students: List[Student] = List(Student(John,Smith,Nothing), Student(Williams,Lopez,Nothing), Student(Thomas,Anderson,Nothing))

scala> students.map(student => student.copy(hobby = hobbies.getOrElse(student.firstName, "Nothing")))
res2: List[Student] = List(Student(John,Smith,Soccer), Student(Williams,Lopez,Cricket), Student(Thomas,Anderson,Nothing))
```